# How can I properly center a JPanel ( FIXED SIZE ) inside a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Hi all!
I'm trying to solve an -apparently- simple problem, but I cannot fix it.
I'm working on a sample application with Java/Swing libraries; 
I have a JFrame and a JPanel.
I just want to achieve the following objectives:

1. JPanel *MUST* be centered inside the JFrame.
2. JPanel *MUST* have *ALWAYS* the size that is specified with
   setPreferredSize() method. It MUST NOT be resized under this size.

I tried by using a GridBagLayout: it's the *ONLY* way I can do it.

See the sample below:

```
/* file StackSample01.java */

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StackSample01 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);  

        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(panel, new GridBagConstraints());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

[Here](http://i1141.photobucket.com/albums/n589/IT00/Screenshot01.png) a screenshot:

I would not use a GridBagLayout to do a thing too simple.
I tried a simplest solution, by using a Box, but this does not work:

Sample code:

```
/* file StackSample02.java */

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StackSample02 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED); // for debug 

        panel.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT); // have no effect

        Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        box.add(panel);     
        box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue()); // causes a deformation

        frame.add(box);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

[Here](http://i1141.photobucket.com/albums/n589/IT00/Screenshot02.png) a screenshot,

Any ideas? Thanks to all :-)

Comment: Have you tried using the BorderFactory class to put a border around "panel"? I'm not too familiar with it, otherwise I'd give a more concrete example.

Comment: *"I would not use a GridBagLayout to do a thing too simple."*  Why not?  I have a deep and abiding dislike of GBL, but for this situation, it would be the first layout I'd try.

Comment: @Andrew - full ack, except using GBL, would never use it :-) Instead go for one of the big-three Form, Mig, Design, whatever is the personal favourite.

Comment: @kleopatra you down voted answers for using setXxxSize(), would you be so nice to provide us a proper answer or a link to a proper answer? I am tired of reading your "-1 for this, -1 for that" comments.

Comment: @mostruash hint: there's a "frequent" tab .. To be honest, I'm tired of developers who don't do much to find the answer to their questions, or the reasons for a vote to answers (up as much as down, doesn't really make a difference) - after all, finding stuff is the _essence_ of their job.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[BoxLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) can  pretty to hold your setXxxSize(), then just add `panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));`

and your output would be

**Removed by setMinimumSize**(*notice if Container has greater size as ... )*

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomComponent12 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomComponent12() {
        Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        box.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        box.add(new CustomComponents12());
        box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        add(box);
        pack();
        setTitle("Custom Component Test / BoxLayout");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMaximumSize(getMinimumSize());
        setMinimumSize(getMinimumSize());
        setPreferredSize(getPreferredSize());
        setLocation(150, 150);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CustomComponent12 main = new CustomComponent12();
            }
        };
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class CustomComponents12 extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int margin = 10;
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width - margin * 2, dim.height - margin * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra somebody can reads between my own lines :-) , my curiosity (and we talking only about deepest JComponents without any childs) how is, or if is possible resurns setXxxSize that another way

Answer (score 6):

First of all, thanks to all.

I reply another time to my own question, to show everyone the choice I have made.
See the sample code below;
As you can see, I have included only minimal steps which are absolutely necessary to achieve the goal.

```
/* file StackResponse.java */

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StackResponse {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Dimension expectedDimension = new Dimension(100, 100);

        panel.setPreferredSize(expectedDimension);
        panel.setMaximumSize(expectedDimension);
        panel.setMinimumSize(expectedDimension);

        panel.setBackground(Color.RED); // for debug only

        Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        box.add(panel);     
        box.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(box);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getMinimumSize());   // cannot be resized-

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

[Here](http://i1141.photobucket.com/albums/n589/IT00/Screenshot-response.png) you can see a screenshot.

Problem solved.
Many thanks again to all.

IT

Answer (score 2):

create a panel by name "FixedPanel" with GridBagLayout and set preferred size to frame size
then add your frame into FixedPanel.

```
Frame = new JFrame("CenterFrame");         
Frame.setLocation(0, 0);
Frame.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));//dim

JPanel FixedPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
FixedPanel.setPreferredSize(Frame.getSize());

JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
myPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

FixedPanel.add(myPanel);
Frame.add(FixedPanel);
Frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this. I had to make a chess game, and I wanted the chess piece piece to always go in the center of a cell which was a JlayeredPane:

```
private void formMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jl != null)
    {
        jl.setLocation(evt.getX()+10, evt.getY()+10);
        Component com = findComponentAt(evt.getPoint());
        if (com instanceof JPanel)
        {
            // System.out.println("Yes, it's a jpanel");
            ((JPanel)com).add(jl);
            ((JPanel)com).validate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Its Just Having

jPanel.setBounds(x, y, 1046, 503);

Where x is space for right side and y is space for left side.
you have to calculate the space from both side according to screen height and width

Answer (score -5):

use

```
panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,200));
panel.setResizable(false)
```

instead?

Comment: JPanel does not have setResizable(boolean resizable) method.

Comment: -1 for setXXSize and inventing api - you know that there's no _obligation_ to answer if you dont know it? Wild guessing _definitely is the wrong-thing-to-do.