# Centering a JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, centering, jcomponent

I have a JPanel that is used to draw the menu for my game and a JFrame that it is added to, I have to add the menu to the middle of the frame so that it will look just as good on a higher resolution as on a lower. I have tried `frame.add(menu, BorderLayout.CENTER)` and `menu.setLocation(windowW / 2, windowH / 2)` but none of these options work. What is the easiest way to accomplish this on?

Comment: Use `LayoutManager`'s: ALWAYS! Don't call `setLocation/setSize/setBounds` as the LayoutManager's will change that anyway (that is their job). Google "Java Swing LayoutManager tutorial" and read the Oracle tutorial. You will quickly see the various possibilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Position a JComponent at the center of a JFrame

use [GridBaglayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) without [override GridBagConstraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830913/714968), or [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) then [JComponent will be placed into center and isn't resizable with container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224700/714968)

Comment: I tried making it work with this code: `Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
            box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
            box.add(menu);
            box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
            frame.add(box);`

Comment: It does place it so that the menu starts in the middle but it cuts the menu of so that it will only show 1/4 of the menu. How would I fix this?

Comment: if I remove the second `box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());` it wont cut the menu of but then it wont be in the middle

Comment: +1, using GridBagLayout is the easiest way to do this. @JavaProgrammer, you were given working examples. We don't know why your code doesn't work. You have a bug in your code. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Java Programmer sorry everything is up to you, nobody knows whats code is dispayed on your sceen, shot to the dark == JFrame.setJMenu....

Comment: got it to work when I changed the class from a JComponent to a JPanel, thanks

Comment: don't forget that JPanel has FlowLayout pre_implemented in API:-) and JComponent haven't any layoutmanager, is required to add some....

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method `frame.setLocationRealtiveTo(null)` or as `parameter` the window where the new frame should be referenced to.

EDIT: Think I understood it wrong. You want to add a component to a `JFrame` to the middle of all. Add instead a `JPanel` to the `JFrame` and add the `component` to the `JPanel` (`BorderLayout.Center`).