# HTML for the Pause symbol in audio and video control

Tags: html, unicode, special-characters, symbols

I'm trying to find the Unicode symbol to make a button display the Unicode pause symbol. I was able to find that the Unicode play symbol is `&#9658` but I'm looking for the equivalent of the Unicode pause symbol.

Comment: Had this same question, but for a "Stop" button (square). [Roko's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27053825/1797628) answer was the best for this.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There are various symbols which could be considered adequate replacements, including:

1. **| |**   - two standard (bolded) vertical bars.
2. ▋▋   - `&#9611;` and another`&#9611;`
3. ▌▌   - `&#9612;` and another`&#9612;`
4. ▍▍ - `&#9613;` and another`&#9613;`
5. ▎▎ - `&#9614;` and another`&#9614;`
6. ❚❚ - `&#10074;` and another `&#10074;`

I may have missed out one or two, but I think these are the better ones. [Here's a list of symbols](http://www.scrollseek.com/wd/html_symbols_complete.html) just in case.

Comment: I used this: .

Comment: &#9646; is the real pause symbol in HTML.

Comment: @JoshuaD if you want to support multiple browsers, you probably shouldn't use that one. I am using the latest Firefox and it isn't readable.

Comment: I used `=` with `transform:rotate(90deg);`.

Comment: @AChildofGod - it's not (only) about the browser, it depends on the fonts installed on your machine.

Comment: I´ve used `&#10074;&#10074;`, which is the in my case best companion to the play symbol `&#9654`.

Answer (score 233):

## Unicode Standard for Media Control Symbols

> ### *Pause:* ⏸︎

The [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org/) [Standard 13.0 *(update 2020)*](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/) provides the [**Miscellaneous Technical**](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2300.pdf) glyphs in the HEX range **2300–23FF**

### Miscellaneous Technical

Given the extensive [Unicode 13.0 documentation](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2300.pdf), some of the glyphs we can associate to common [Media control symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_control_symbols) would be as following:

> #### *Keyboard and UI symbols*
>
> 23CF  ⏏︎ Eject media
>
> #### *User interface symbols*
>
> 23E9  ⏩︎ fast forward
>   23EA  ⏪︎ rewind, fast backwards
>   23EB  ⏫︎ fast increase
>   23EC  ⏬︎ fast decrease
>   23ED  ⏭︎ skip to end, next
>   23EE  ⏮︎ skip to start, previous
>   23EF  ⏯︎ play/pause toggle
>   23F1  ⏱︎ stopwatch
>   23F2  ⏲︎ timer clock
>   23F3  ⏳︎ hourglass
>   23F4  ⏴︎ reverse, back
>   23F5  ⏵︎ forward, next, play
>   23F6  ⏶︎ increase
>   23F7  ⏷︎ decrease
>   23F8  ⏸︎ pause
>   23F9  ⏹︎ stop
>   23FA  ⏺︎ record
>
> #### *Power symbols from ISO 7000:2012*
>
> 23FB ⏻︎ standby/power
>   23FC ⏼︎ power on/off
>   23FD ⏽︎ power on
>   2B58 ⭘︎ power off
>
> #### *Power symbol from IEEE 1621-2004*
>
> 23FE ⏾︎ power sleep

## Use on the Web:

A file must be saved using [UTF-8 encoding](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings#applyingencoding) [without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/383904) (which in most development environments is set by default) in order to instruct the parser how to transform the bytes into characters correctly.  `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` should be used immediately after `<head>` in a [HTML file](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations), and make sure the correct HTTP headers `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` are set.

Examples:

HTML

```html
&#x23E9; Pictograph 
&#x23E9;&#xFE0E; Standardized Variant
```

CSS

```css
.icon-ff:before { content: "\23E9" }
.icon-ff--standard:before { content: "\23E9\FE0E" }
```

JavaScript

```js
EL_iconFF.textContent = "\u23E9";
EL_iconFF_standard.textContent = "\u23E9\uFE0E"
```

### Standardized variant

To prevent a glyph from being *"color-emojified"* ⏩︎ / ⏩ **append** the code U+FE0E ***[Text Presentation Selector](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#def_text_presentation_selector)*** to request a [**Standardized variant**](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.0.0/ucd/StandardizedVariants.html):  (example: `&#x23e9;&#xfe0e;`)

### Inconsistencies

Characters in the Unicode range are susceptible to the font-family environment they are used, application, browser, OS, platform.
When [*unknown*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) or [*missing*](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch05.pdf#G7730) - we might see symbols like � or ▯ instead, or even **inconsistent behavior** due to differences in HTML parser implementations by different vendors.
For example, on **Windows** Chromium browsers the Standardized Variant suffix U+FE0E is buggy, and such symbols are still better accompanied by CSS i.e:  `font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol"` to force that specific Font over the Colored Emoji (usually recognized as "Segoe UI Emoji") - which defies the purpose of U+FE0E in the first place - time will tell…

---

## Scalable icon fonts

To circumvent problems related to **unsupported characters** - a viable solution is to  use **scalable icon font-sets** like i.e:

### [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#video-player)

[image: Player icons - scalable - font awesome]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
<i class="fa fa-backward"></i>
<i class="fa fa-compress"></i>
<i class="fa fa-eject"></i>
<i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
<i class="fa fa-fast-backward"></i>
<i class="fa fa-fast-forward"></i>
<i class="fa fa-forward"></i>
<i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
<i class="fa fa-play"></i>
<i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
<i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
<i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>
<i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>
<i class="fa fa-stop"></i>
<i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
```

### [Google](https://design.google.com/icons/) [Icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/README.md)

[image]

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons">pause</i>
<i class="material-icons">pause_circle_filled</i>
<i class="material-icons">pause_circle_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">fast_forward</i>
<i class="material-icons">fast_rewind</i>
<i class="material-icons">fiber_manual_record</i>
<i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i>
<i class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i>
<i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">skip_next</i>
<i class="material-icons">skip_previous</i>
<i class="material-icons">replay</i>
<i class="material-icons">repeat</i>
<i class="material-icons">stop</i>
<i class="material-icons">loop</i>
<i class="material-icons">mic</i>
<i class="material-icons">volume_up</i>
<i class="material-icons">volume_down</i>
<i class="material-icons">volume_mute</i>
<i class="material-icons">volume_off</i>
```

and many other you can find in the wild;  and last but not least, this really useful online tool: [font-icons generator, **Icomoon.io**](https://icomoon.io/).

---

Comment: Annoyingly there's no "circled stop" button in the Google font/icons, so their "circled play" and "circled pause" set is incomplete...

Comment: @Fizz https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/851

Comment: Awesome Answer - I love the effort that was put into it. Did you notice the official "ISO 7000 / IEC 60417 Symbol for Pause; Interruption is #5111B. See Media_Controls", which was pointed to by @intotecho in this underrated answer? → https://stackoverflow.com/a/48918561/4575793

Comment: The text presentation selector `&#xfe0e;` like in `&#x25B6;&#xfe0e;` does not seem to work in Firefox and Chrome for android (2020 AC).

Comment: The pause symbol (23F8) renders has an *orange* frame on Android (with font color black) and is super tall on Firefox/Chromium on Linux. Doesn't seem to be reliable cross-platform in 2021 :/

Comment: @Luc Does it also happens using the **Standardized variant** as explained in a paragraph above?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Unfortunately it also happens when that is appended, specifically when using `&#x23F8;&#xfe0e;`, although I actually missed that paragraph before first commenting so thanks for the hint regardless!

Comment: @Luc After a second look, it also happens here on Stack Overflow (Windows 10, Chrome  91.0.4x) on that same Answer post. The first time I load the page I see the Emoji and only after a page refresh (without hard refresh) I finally see the Standardized variant being applied. I Already reported that (similar) bug to Chrome. A year ago...

Answer (score 64):

Following may come in handy:

- ⏩ `&#x23e9;`
- ⏪ `&#x23ea;`
- ⏫ `&#x24eb;`
- ⏬ `&#x23ec;`
- ⏭ `&#x23ed;`
- ⏮ `&#x23ee;`
- ⏯ `&#x23ef;`
- ⏴ `&#x23f4;`
- ⏵ `&#x23f5;`
- ⏶ `&#x23f6;`
- ⏷ `&#x23f7;`
- ⏸ `&#x23f8;`
- ⏹ `&#x23f9;`
- ⏺ `&#x23fa;`

**NOTE**: apparently, these characters aren't very well supported in popular fonts, so if you plan to use it on the web, be sure to pick a webfont that supports these.

Answer (score 29):

▐▐  is HTML and is made with this code: `&#9616;&#9616;`.

[Here's an example JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jEZY8/)

Answer (score 23):

I found it, it’s in the Miscellaneous Technical block.
⏸ (U+23F8)

Comment: Not sure how the right answer got downvoted.  See link below where this "double vertical bar" is also noted as "pause" in its comments.  Too bad it doesn't seem to be well supported in the fonts (added to Unicode in June 2014).

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23f8/index.htm

Answer (score 16):

I'm using ▐ ▌

HTML: `&#9616;&nbsp;&#9612;`

CSS: `\2590\A0\258C`

Answer (score 7):

If you want one that's a single character to match the right-facing triangle for "play," try Roman numeral 2. Ⅱ is `&#8545;` in HTML.  If you can put formatting tags around it, it looks really good in bold. **Ⅱ** is `<b>&#8545;</b>` in HTML. This has much better support than the previously mentioned double vertical bar.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned making it bold.  I'm using &#2405; and it looks better in bold.

Answer (score 5):

Modern browsers support 'DOUBLE VERTICAL BAR' (U+23F8), too:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23f8/index.htm

For a music player it can act as a companion for 'BLACK RIGHT-POINTING POINTER' (U+25BA) because they both share equal width and height making it perfect for a play/pause button:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ba/index.htm

Comment: On mac double vertical bar is surrounded by a skeuomorphic box looks different from black right-pointing pointer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no character encoded for use as a pause symbol, though various characters or combinations of characters may look more or less like a pause symbol, depending on font.

In a discussion in the public Unicode mailing list in 2005, a [suggestion](http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2005-m08/0367.html) was made to use two copies of the U+275A HEAVY VERTICAL BAR character: ❚❚. But the adequacy of the result depends on font; for example, the glyph might have been designed so that the bars are too much apart. – The list discussion explains why a pause symbol had not been encoded, and this has not changed.

Thus, the best option is to use an image. If you need to use the symbol in text, it is best to create it in a suitably large size (say 60 by 60 pixels) and scale it down to text size with CSS (e.g., setting `height: 0.8em` on the `img` element).

Comment: You can also add some CSS like "letter-spacing: -6px" to the double Heavy Vertical Bar, so it it looks more like a real pause symbol. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/enKaA/

Comment: This is better than #9616 since it's the same height.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Unicode 7.0 (released 2014) has added U+23F8 and matching symbols (play, stop, record) precisely for this purpose https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-7.0/U70-2300.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The ISO 7000 / IEC 60417 Symbol for Pause; Interruption is 
#5111B. 
See [Media_Controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_controls)

Answer (score 0):

I found a good option similar to the others but exact with the  span tag. You can apply

```
<span>&#9616;</span>&#9616;
```

with no spaces.

Comment: You are missing the 'x' after '#'. You should test before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply **II** looks good! Other idea:

- Pause II: just two capital letters i, ie. roman two (font dependent, needs sans serif)
- Pause **II**: as before, but bold
- Pause ll: two small letters L
- Pause ||: two vertical bars
- Pause ": quote
- Pause ᐦ: 0x1426 Canadian syllabics final double short vertical strokes
- Pause ‖: 0x2016 double vertical line*

Partly inspried by https://shapecatcher.com.

```html
<div style="font-family: Roboto">
Pause II: just two capital letters i (font dependent, needs sans serif)<br>
Pause <b>II</b>: as before, but bold<br>
Pause ll: two small letters L<br>
Pause ||: two vertical bars<br>
Pause ": quote<br>
Pause &#x1426;: 0x1426 Canadian syllabics final double short vertical strokes<br>
Pause &#x2016;: 0x2016 double vertical line<br>
<div/>
```